# ElasticSearch - Determining which terms matched no documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a filtered query with a terms filter, is there any way to determine which terms in the filter matched no documents? In other words, determine the redundant terms in the filter?

Alternatively is it possible to specify an aggregation that counts matches for the *filter* terms rather than the unique terms in the matching documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Filters Aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html).

Comment: Yes - that works. In my use case where there are a high number of terms it makes for a pretty verbose query but it does what I need. Thanks.